# how do I remove the rounding of prices after the comma in order

Tags: woocommerce, price

how do I remove the rounding of prices after the comma in order . I am attaching the picture to understand. thank you[price with a comma, how can I add 2 digits after the comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq1kH.png) [rounded price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD4gw.png) correctly it would be 3x5.88 = 17.64 .... but 17.65 appears to me, how can I fix this problem. thank you

Thanks to those who help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the number_format function in PHP. It allows you to format a number with decimal points and commas.

```
<?php

$price = 17.64;
$formatted_price = number_format($price, 2, '.', '');
echo $formatted_price; // output: 17.64
```

By using the number_format function with a precision of 2, you can format the price without rounding it. Not sure if this is what you are looking for, hope it helps.